Counting Issue in Tableau
I am working with a live data stream in Tableau and don't have any control over the data. I am encountering an issue where I am getting two different values that should be the same. The first count is distinct by academic year; the second is by distinct Year and Department. Here is some sample data that I made to mimic the issue; this is the R code used to generate the data.
set.seed(101)
data.frame(ID= sample.int(c(1:20), size= 30, replace= T),
 Year= sample(c("Y1", "Y2"), size= 30, replace= T),
 DEPT= sample(c("ENHS", "EPID", "BIOS", "COMD"), size= 30,replace= T),
 DEG= sample(c("MA", "MS", "CGS", "PHD"), size= 30, replace= T) %>%
Arrange(Year, ID) %>%
slice(-c(2, 7, 12, 29, 23, 27, 29))

I deleted rows 2, 7, 12, 19, 23, 27, and 29 to make the data more realistic.
In Tableau,  to count by Academic Year, I am using a fixed LOD expression of
SUM({Fixed [Year]: COUNTD([ID])}), Y1= 8.
SUM({Fixed [Year], [DEPT]: COUNTD([ID]), Y1= 10, because of the CGS degrees.
I have tried to remove the "CGS" from Degrees, but it removes all students with that type of degree. How would you approach keeping the students with only a "CGS" DEG and discarding the "CGS" when a student has more than one DEPT? I am a beginner in Tableau, and their message board is confusing.

There is a lot crammed into this question making it hard to give you a quick answer. If you can simplify it to show a small table of input data in CSV style instead of R, the result you get and the result you expect instead, then it would be easier to help you

A few general  points, don’t use LOD calcs unless you have a good reason to, try to just use dimensions first. LOD calcs are useful, just overly constrained/complex than necessary in many cases. Don’t use COUNTD() when SUM() or COUNT() will do. Note, that you are further aggregating the LOD results with SUM(), so if a person appears in two departments they would be counted twice.

Thank you! I filtered the data stream and removed them completely. Now everything is computing correctly. I use the LOD computations because I have a lot of cleaning since I don't own the data.
